# Python - Multiple 'split' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I posted here 4-5 days ago, about one problem to sort some numbers from file.
Now, is the same of the other problem but, I want to sort numbers from one file (x) to another file (y). For example: In x i have: (5,6,3,11,7), and I want to sort this numbers to y (3,5,6,7,11). But I have some errors and can't resolve on my own, I do not understand them, can you help me?

```
from sys import argv
try:
    with open(argv[1],"r") as desti:
        cad = desti.readlines()
        k= list(cad)
        for n in range(len(cad)):
            k = n.split(',') 
            k = (int, cad)
            k = sorted(cad)
        with open("nums_ordenats.txt","w") as prl:
            prl.write(k)
except Exception as err:
    print(err, "Error")
```

Actually, the error message is " 'int' object has no attribute 'split' Error
". 
I think the code is correct. Also, the program says me other errors, but how im changintg code everytime, they also change.

Tanks a lot!

Comment: `n` is an integer, not a string. This is why you're getting this error.

Comment: `n` is an integer. Maybe you mean `cad[n].split(',')`?

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks to all (I edited code from post). Now the error is : " list indices must be integers, not str Error
". Really, i can't understand this errors, I've been trying to do this program shit for more than 1 week, which I think is very simply to do.

Comment: Do your files have `(5,6,3,11,7)` including the brackets, or just `5,6,3,11,7`?

Comment: Sorry @abccd, now it's the same of start question, the same code.

Comment: @AlexHall No, without brackets, it's a simple plane text with random numbers to sort. Only separate with commas.

Comment: Of course the code is not correct if it crashes. Possibly the algorithm you have in mind is correct, but not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many problems with your code for me to address. Try this:

```
from sys import argv

with open(argv[1], "r") as infile:
    with open("nums_ordenats.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            nums = [int(n) for n in line.split(',')]
            nums.sort()
            outfile.write(','.join([str(n) for n in nums]))
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: My god dude, thank you very much, really! Now I will try to understand it and edit for me.